# Confusion in structure, tMap

Tags: sql, oracle, business-intelligence, talend

I have a dimension table called `Product_Dim`

```
Create Table Product_Dim
(
Product_ID INT primary key,
Product_Line CHAR(20),
Product_Category CHAR(25),
Product_Group CHAR(25),
Product_Name CHAR(45),
Supplier_Country CHAR(2),
Supplier_Name CHAR(30),
Supplier_ID INT
)
```

and two source tables `Supplier` and `Product_List`

Product_list is as follow :

```
Product_ID
Product_Name
Supplier_ID
Product_Level
Product_Ref_ID
```

where Product_Level has the values (1,2,3,4)

1 means it is a product
2 means it is a product group
3 means it is a product category
4 means it is a product line

so in order to fill my `Product_Dim` table
I did drag 4 times `Product_list` (Changing the query accordingly to `Product_level`)
and one supplier

so for the join i do the following :

```
 product_list.Product_Name  => PRoduct_Name
 product_group.Product_Name  => PRoduct_Group
 product_line.Product_Name  => PRoduct_line
 product_group.Product_category  => PRoduct_category
 ....
```

My problem is in the `product_ID`

I don't know what to drag in there, I thought on dragging the four `Product_ID`s but I don't know what expression to write.

Any help will be appreciate it.

EDIT :
`Product_Dim`

```
 Product_ID Product_Name Product_line Product_group ...
 1          PN1
 2          PN2
            ....
 3                       PL1
 4                       PL2
                         ....
 5                                     PG1
 6                                     PG2
                                       ...
 ....
```

and so on, but i dont know how to do this.

Comment: Did you read the Talend user guide ? Which Talend product are you using ?

Comment: I am using TOS-All-r67267 - V4.2.3 I found in sourceforge, it is TalendOpenStudio-win32-x86.

IMO i need to find an expression for the Product_ID column, [link to a screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/f32lxgt75/full/), all products table have the same structure except for Product_Dim, they only have different queries.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what are you trying to achieve ? Your question is not really a question since I don't see one in your post.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, well from the image in my above comment, you can see that all columns have their respective match except for Product_ID in Product_Dim Table, I am confused cuz all 4 table product_list, product_category, product_line and product group have the same structure, in fact all i did was drag the table product 4 times and change the query as i explained in the main question, i dont know how to fill Product_ID in Product_Dim table, logically it should be as follow (please look at the edit in the main question)

Comment: Why don't you take product ID from the product list table ? I don't get it. Please read this : http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?language=english&idTuto=6

Comment: Thanks again, I didnt take it from product list table because it only has rows where product_level = 1, product group table has only the rows where product_level = 2, product category ... where product_level = 3, i want to combine the Product_ids of all the 4 table, i am sorry i am not explaining well :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it was hard but I get your problem.

Well the first solution that comes to my mind, is to split that in 4 tMap components.

This should solve your problem.

[image]